# MySql FullText index taking more time to retrieve the result data

Tags: mysql, full-text-indexing

```
 explain SELECT *   FROM PersistentQueues.RequestQueue where 
            MATCH (`data`) AGAINST ('{ "test": { "test": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1001, 111, 201, 222, 3333, 888, 99, 88, 66, 324, 785, 952, 657, 458, 632, 746, 854, 421, 351, 364, 819, 816, 674, 487, 796, 652, 20011, 3001, 4574, 7893, 4785, 84210, 36201, 7584, 6954, 7521, 1741, 2145, 58, 1001598594, 1001598593, 1001598592, 1001598599, 1001598598, 1001598597, 1001598596, 1001598603, 1001598602, 1001598601, 1001598600, 1001598607, 1001598606, 1001598605, 1001598604, 1001598707, 1001598706, 1001598705, 1001598704, 1001598711, 1001598710, 1001598709, 1001598708, 1001598715, 1001598714, 1001598713, 1001598712, 1001598718, 1001598717, 1001598716, 1001598691, 1001598690, 1001598689, 1001598688, 1001598695, 1001598694, 1001598693, 1001598692, 1001598699, 1001598698, 1001598697, 1001598696, 1001598703, 1001598702, 1001598701, 1001598700, 1001598675, 1001598674, 1001598673, 1001598672, 1001598679, 1001598678, 1001598677, 1001598676, 1001598683, 1001598682, 1001598681, 1001598680, 1001598687, 1001598686, 1001598685, 1001598684, 1001598659, 1001598658, 1001598657, 1001598656, 1001598663, 1001598662, 1001598661, 1001598660, 1001598667, 1001598666, 1001598665, 1001598664, 1001598671, 1001598670, 1001598669, 1001598668, 1001598515, 1001598514, 1001598513, 1001598512, 1001598519, 1001598518, 1001598517, 1001598516, 1001598523, 1001598522, 1001598521, 1001598520, 1001598527, 1001598526, 1001598525, 1001598524, 1001598499, 1001598498, 1001598497, 1001598496, 1001598503, 1001598502, 1001598501, 1001598500, 1001598507, 1001598506, 1001598505, 1001598504, 1001598511, 1001598510, 1001598509, 1001598508, 1001598483, 1001598482, 1001598481, 1001598480, 1001598487, 1001598486, 1001598485, 1001598484, 1001598491, 1001598490, 1001598489, 1001598488, 1001598495, 1001598494, 1001598493, 1001598492, 1001598467, 1001598466, 1001598465, 1001598464, 1001598471, 1001598470, 1001598469, 1001598468, 1001598475, 1001598474, 1001598473, 1001598472, 1001598479, 1001598478, 1001598477, 1001598476, 1001598579, 1001598578, 1001598577, 1001598576, 1001598583, 1001598582, 1001598581, 1001598580, 1001598587, 1001598586, 1001598585, 1001598584, 1001598591, 1001598590, 1001598589, 1001598588, 1001598563, 1001598562, 1001598561, 1001598560, 1001598567, 1001598566, 1001598565, 1001598564, 1001598571, 1001598570, 1001598569, 1001598568, 1001598575, 1001598574, 1001598573, 1001598572, 1001598547, 1001598546, 1001598545, 1001598544, 1001598551, 1001598550, 1001598549, 1001598548, 1001598555, 1001598554, 1001598553, 1001598552, 1001598559, 1001598558, 1001598557, 1001598556, 1001598531, 1001598530, 1001598529, 1001598528, 1001598535, 1001598534, 1001598533, 1001598532, 1001598539, 1001598538, 1001598537, 1001598536, 1001598543, 1001598542, 1001598541, 1001598540, 1001598387, 1001598386, 1001598385, 1001598384, 1001598391, 1001598390, 1001598389, 1001598388, 1001598395, 1001598394, 1001598393, 1001598392, 1001598399, 1001598398, 1001598397, 1001598396, 1001598371, 1001598370, 1001598369, 1001598368, 1001598375, 1001598374, 1001598373, 1001598372, 1001598379, 1001598378, 1001598377, 1001598376, 1001598383, 1001598382, 1001598381, 1001598380, 1001598355, 1001598354, 1001598353, 1001598352, 1001598359, 1001598358, 1001598357, 1001598356, 1001598363, 1001598362, 1001598361, 1001598360, 1001598367, 1001598366, 1001598365, 1001598364, 1001598339, 1001598338, 1001598337, 1001598336, 1001598343, 1001598342, 1001598341, 1001598340, 1001598347, 1001598346, 1001598345, 1001598344, 1001598351, 1001598350, 1001598349, 1001598348, 1001598451, 1001598450, 1001598449, 1001598448, 1001598455, 1001598454, 1001598453, 1001598452, 1001598459, 1001598458, 1001598457, 1001598456, 1001598463, 1001598462, 1001598461, 1001598460, 1001598435, 1001598434, 1001598433, 1001598432, 1001598439, 1001598438, 1001598437, 1001598436, 1001598443, 1001598442, 1001598441, 1001598440, 1001598447, 1001598446, 1001598445, 1001598444, 1001598419, 1001598418, 1001598417, 1001598416, 1001598423, 1001598422, 1001598421, 1001598420, 1001598427, 1001598426, 1001598425, 1001598424, 1001598431, 1001598430, 1001598429, 1001598428, 1001598403, 1001598402, 1001598401, 1001598400, 1001598407, 1001598406, 1001598405, 1001598404, 1001598411, 1001598410, 1001598409, 1001598408, 1001598415, 1001598414, 1001598413, 1001598412, 1001598259, 1001598258, 1001598257, 1001598256, 1001598263, 1001598262, 1001598261, 1001598260, 1001598267, 1001598266, 1001598265, 1001598264, 1001598271, 1001598270, 1001598269, 1001598268, 1001598243, 1001598242, 1001598241, 1001598240, 1001598247, 1001598246, 1001598245, 1001598244, 1001598251, 1001598250, 1001598249, 1001598248, 1001598255, 1001598254, 1001598253, 1001598252, 1001598227, 1001598226, 1001598225, 1001598224, 1001598231, 1001598230, 1001598229, 1001598228, 1001598235, 1001598234, 1001598233, 1001598232, 1001598239, 1001598238, 1001598237, 1001598236, 1001598219, 1001598223, 1001598222, 1001598221, 1001598220, 1001598323, 1001598322, 1001598321, 1001598320, 1001598327, 1001598326, 1001598325, 1001598324, 1001598331, 1001598330, 1001598329, 1001598328, 1001598335, 1001598334, 1001598333, 1001598332, 1001598307, 1001598306, 1001598305, 1001598304, 1001598311, 1001598310, 1001598309, 1001598308, 1001598315, 1001598314, 1001598313, 1001598312, 1001598319, 1001598318, 1001598317, 1001598316, 1001598291, 1001598290, 1001598289, 1001598288, 1001598295, 1001598294, 1001598293, 1001598292, 1001598299, 1001598298, 1001598297, 1001598296, 1001598303, 1001598302, 1001598301, 1001598300, 1001598275, 1001598274, 1001598273, 1001598272, 1001598279, 1001598278, 1001598277, 1001598276, 1001598283, 1001598282, 1001598281, 1001598280, 1001598287, 1001598286, 1001598285, 1001598284], "operation": "UPSERT" } }') 
            AND `data` like '%{ "test": { "test": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1001, 111, 201, 222, 3333, 888, 99, 88, 66, 324, 785, 952, 657, 458, 632, 746, 854, 421, 351, 364, 819, 816, 674, 487, 796, 652, 20011, 3001, 4574, 7893, 4785, 84210, 36201, 7584, 6954, 7521, 1741, 2145, 58, 1001598594, 1001598593, 1001598592, 1001598599, 1001598598, 1001598597, 1001598596, 1001598603, 1001598602, 1001598601, 1001598600, 1001598607, 1001598606, 1001598605, 1001598604, 1001598707, 1001598706, 1001598705, 1001598704, 1001598711, 1001598710, 1001598709, 1001598708, 1001598715, 1001598714, 1001598713, 1001598712, 1001598718, 1001598717, 1001598716, 1001598691, 1001598690, 1001598689, 1001598688, 1001598695, 1001598694, 1001598693, 1001598692, 1001598699, 1001598698, 1001598697, 1001598696, 1001598703, 1001598702, 1001598701, 1001598700, 1001598675, 1001598674, 1001598673, 1001598672, 1001598679, 1001598678, 1001598677, 1001598676, 1001598683, 1001598682, 1001598681, 1001598680, 1001598687, 1001598686, 1001598685, 1001598684, 1001598659, 1001598658, 1001598657, 1001598656, 1001598663, 1001598662, 1001598661, 1001598660, 1001598667, 1001598666, 1001598665, 1001598664, 1001598671, 1001598670, 1001598669, 1001598668, 1001598515, 1001598514, 1001598513, 1001598512, 1001598519, 1001598518, 1001598517, 1001598516, 1001598523, 1001598522, 1001598521, 1001598520, 1001598527, 1001598526, 1001598525, 1001598524, 1001598499, 1001598498, 1001598497, 1001598496, 1001598503, 1001598502, 1001598501, 1001598500, 1001598507, 1001598506, 1001598505, 1001598504, 1001598511, 1001598510, 1001598509, 1001598508, 1001598483, 1001598482, 1001598481, 1001598480, 1001598487, 1001598486, 1001598485, 1001598484, 1001598491, 1001598490, 1001598489, 1001598488, 1001598495, 1001598494, 1001598493, 1001598492, 1001598467, 1001598466, 1001598465, 1001598464, 1001598471, 1001598470, 1001598469, 1001598468, 1001598475, 1001598474, 1001598473, 1001598472, 1001598479, 1001598478, 1001598477, 1001598476, 1001598579, 1001598578, 1001598577, 1001598576, 1001598583, 1001598582, 1001598581, 1001598580, 1001598587, 1001598586, 1001598585, 1001598584, 1001598591, 1001598590, 1001598589, 1001598588, 1001598563, 1001598562, 1001598561, 1001598560, 1001598567, 1001598566, 1001598565, 1001598564, 1001598571, 1001598570, 1001598569, 1001598568, 1001598575, 1001598574, 1001598573, 1001598572, 1001598547, 1001598546, 1001598545, 1001598544, 1001598551, 1001598550, 1001598549, 1001598548, 1001598555, 1001598554, 1001598553, 1001598552, 1001598559, 1001598558, 1001598557, 1001598556, 1001598531, 1001598530, 1001598529, 1001598528, 1001598535, 1001598534, 1001598533, 1001598532, 1001598539, 1001598538, 1001598537, 1001598536, 1001598543, 1001598542, 1001598541, 1001598540, 1001598387, 1001598386, 1001598385, 1001598384, 1001598391, 1001598390, 1001598389, 1001598388, 1001598395, 1001598394, 1001598393, 1001598392, 1001598399, 1001598398, 1001598397, 1001598396, 1001598371, 1001598370, 1001598369, 1001598368, 1001598375, 1001598374, 1001598373, 1001598372, 1001598379, 1001598378, 1001598377, 1001598376, 1001598383, 1001598382, 1001598381, 1001598380, 1001598355, 1001598354, 1001598353, 1001598352, 1001598359, 1001598358, 1001598357, 1001598356, 1001598363, 1001598362, 1001598361, 1001598360, 1001598367, 1001598366, 1001598365, 1001598364, 1001598339, 1001598338, 1001598337, 1001598336, 1001598343, 1001598342, 1001598341, 1001598340, 1001598347, 1001598346, 1001598345, 1001598344, 1001598351, 1001598350, 1001598349, 1001598348, 1001598451, 1001598450, 1001598449, 1001598448, 1001598455, 1001598454, 1001598453, 1001598452, 1001598459, 1001598458, 1001598457, 1001598456, 1001598463, 1001598462, 1001598461, 1001598460, 1001598435, 1001598434, 1001598433, 1001598432, 1001598439, 1001598438, 1001598437, 1001598436, 1001598443, 1001598442, 1001598441, 1001598440, 1001598447, 1001598446, 1001598445, 1001598444, 1001598419, 1001598418, 1001598417, 1001598416, 1001598423, 1001598422, 1001598421, 1001598420, 1001598427, 1001598426, 1001598425, 1001598424, 1001598431, 1001598430, 1001598429, 1001598428, 1001598403, 1001598402, 1001598401, 1001598400, 1001598407, 1001598406, 1001598405, 1001598404, 1001598411, 1001598410, 1001598409, 1001598408, 1001598415, 1001598414, 1001598413, 1001598412, 1001598259, 1001598258, 1001598257, 1001598256, 1001598263, 1001598262, 1001598261, 1001598260, 1001598267, 1001598266, 1001598265, 1001598264, 1001598271, 1001598270, 1001598269, 1001598268, 1001598243, 1001598242, 1001598241, 1001598240, 1001598247, 1001598246, 1001598245, 1001598244, 1001598251, 1001598250, 1001598249, 1001598248, 1001598255, 1001598254, 1001598253, 1001598252, 1001598227, 1001598226, 1001598225, 1001598224, 1001598231, 1001598230, 1001598229, 1001598228, 1001598235, 1001598234, 1001598233, 1001598232, 1001598239, 1001598238, 1001598237, 1001598236, 1001598219, 1001598223, 1001598222, 1001598221, 1001598220, 1001598323, 1001598322, 1001598321, 1001598320, 1001598327, 1001598326, 1001598325, 1001598324, 1001598331, 1001598330, 1001598329, 1001598328, 1001598335, 1001598334, 1001598333, 1001598332, 1001598307, 1001598306, 1001598305, 1001598304, 1001598311, 1001598310, 1001598309, 1001598308, 1001598315, 1001598314, 1001598313, 1001598312, 1001598319, 1001598318, 1001598317, 1001598316, 1001598291, 1001598290, 1001598289, 1001598288, 1001598295, 1001598294, 1001598293, 1001598292, 1001598299, 1001598298, 1001598297, 1001598296, 1001598303, 1001598302, 1001598301, 1001598300, 1001598275, 1001598274, 1001598273, 1001598272, 1001598279, 1001598278, 1001598277, 1001598276, 1001598283, 1001598282, 1001598281, 1001598280, 1001598287, 1001598286, 1001598285, 1001598284], "operation": "UPSERT" } }%' 
            AND successfulOperations = 0;
```

Explain result:

[image]

Profiling result:

[image]

Why it's taking more time?

Note: The query is not returning the result. I have killed the query. Also, the Table contains more than 100 million records.

Comment: I recommend not to use Indian words here. People aren't going to understand what are "crore records", and formatting your question so that it's not filled with your SQL also helps to get people to help you. @GMB already did it for you, but you messed up the question again.

Comment: your approach on searching data is very not effective.   Index will have hard time finding your data if that contains millions of records.  
Try a different approach, or make schema design that enables you to match records as intended.

Comment: @dodzb Could you please suggest some approach?